# disjoint compact subsets of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology

What would be some compact subsets of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ which are disjoint? I know that the set of convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is one compact subset, but what would be another which is disjoint to it? Thank you!

Comment: How exactly is the set of convergent sequences in $\mathbb R^n$ compact? Any convergent sequence can be multiplied by a constant and remain convergent, you don't even have boundedness.

Comment: is that so? then what can be a subset of $\ell^\infty$? thank you

Comment: You can always take $2$ disjoint finite subsets, if that's all you need.

Comment: can you give me a precise example? thank you. what i really need are disjoint compact subsets which have distance equal to 0.

Comment: That's not possible. See my comments to your last question. In a complete metric space, the distance between compact sets $A$ and $B$ is attained by some elements $a\in A$, $b\in B$.

Comment: but for closed subsets, can i find such subsets with distance equal to 0?

Comment: Please edit your question. You are obviously not looking for $2$ disjoint compact subsets of $l^{\infty}$.

Comment: Yes. Take, e.g., the set of unit vectors, $\{e_n|n\in\Bbb N\}$, and the set $\{(1+1/n)e_n | n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: thank you @david. does closed and boundedness on $\ell^\infty$ imply compactness? or not necessary?

Comment: No. Neither of the sets in my previous comment are compact, e.g. You can find a characterization of compactness in $\ell_\infty$ in my comments to your last question.

Comment: that's what i really thought of. thank you very much. can you please give me other examples of closed and bounded subsets with distance zero? just for clarity purposes. thank you very much @david!